# Displaying a product page with a list of all available relationships of a relationship field shown as a list, with the selected relationship flagged

Tags: status, related-entries, reverse-related-entries, related

My client needs to display the status of an order, so using relationship channel of order_statuses.

The list of order statuses should be shown as:

- Order recieved
- Status 2
- [TICK] Status 3
- Status 4
- Status 5
- Order Complete

The tick shows that the order is at a specific point in the process...

I could probably use statuses, but need it to sit within a channel to give me more flexibility over what it can store. eg. status icon etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use an embed template inside the product to call all your "status" entries:

Product template example

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products"}
    
    <!-- products title -->
    {title} 

    <!-- call embed template with status id as reference -->
    {embed="my_group/my_embed_template" the_status_id="{status_relationship_field:entry_id}"}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Embed template example:

```
<ul>
<!-- loop through all statuses -->
{exp:channel:entries channel="order_statuses" dynamic="no"}
<li>
    <!-- compare order statuses entry id with embed reference from product -->
    {if entry_id == '{embed:the_status_id}'}<img src="{status_icon}">{/if} 
    <!--  orders status title -->
    {title}
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</ul>
```

Something like that!